# How to get the file name of a file which is transferred via wifi direct in android?

Tags: android, file-transfer, wifi-direct

I have seen an example about this question.But when I have a try on it , it just occur an error in this code `File f = new File(Uri.parse(uri.toString()));` and just say that Constructor File(Uri) is undefined . I have stucked in this error for many days. I don't know what's wrong with it because other people can work. The following is the suggested code

```
public class WiFiDirectBundle extends Serializable {
    private String fileName;
    private String mimeType;
    private Long fileSize;
    private byte[] fileContent;

    public WiFiDirectBundle() {}

    // adds a file to the bundle, given its URI
    public void setFile(Uri uri) {
        File f = new File(Uri.parse(uri.toString()));

        fileName = f.getName();
        mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(f.getAbsolutePath());
        fileSize = f.length();

        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(f);        
        fileContent = new byte[(int) f.length()];
        fin.read(fileContent);
    }

    // restores the file of the bundle, given its directory (change to whatever
    // fits you better)
    public String restoreFile(String baseDir) {
        File f = new File(baseDir + "/" + fileName);
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
            if (fileContent != null) {
                fos.write(fileContent);
            }

            fos.close();
            return f.getAbsolutePath();

        } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    public String getMimeType() {
        return mimeType;
    }

    public Long getFileSize() {
        return fileSize;
    }
}
```

And this is original qusetion:
[How to find file name of a file which is transferred via wifi direct mode in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965446/how-to-find-file-name-of-a-file-which-is-transferred-via-wifi-direct-mode-in-and/16783896#16783896)
Also I am a beginner in Wifi Direct ,I can successfully link two device and transfer file  ,but I want to linked more device and transfer file Sequentially can anyone give me some advices about learning it or some examples about how to do it.Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find file name of a file which is transferred via wifi direct mode in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965446/how-to-find-file-name-of-a-file-which-is-transferred-via-wifi-direct-mode-in-and)

Comment: I have saw that question(in my question I also have said that).I had tried it but occured the error in my question,so I want to ask again to see who can help me about this error.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use

```
File f = new File(uri.getPath());
```

instead of

```
File f = new File(Uri.parse(uri.toString()));
```

to get file path from Uri

Comment: Thanks for your answer!I just tried your suggest but in the following two line it occur other errors `FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(f);` `and fin.read(fileContent); `
it said Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException and Unhandled exception type IOException separately. How should I do to deal with the new errors?

Comment: @dddog : jsut debug your code using Logs and check  you are getting valid path from `uri.getPath()`

Answer (score 0):

you can open inputstream of a file from its uri using content resolver
ContentResolver cr=getContentResolver();
InputStream in=cr.OpenInputStream(file_uri);
you can use this input stream to read from the file